# Button to update layout_weight doesn't take effect

Tags: kotlin, layoutparams

I am using this code in kotlin to update the layout_weight of a linear_layout as an indication. When the button is pressed though, the layout weight doesn't change.

This will eventually be a fun app using random updates but for now I want to make sure that the code works.
predWt is the button id
physWt is the linearlayout id (currently set with weight 0.3)

```
        predWt.setOnClickListener {
        physWt.layoutParams.apply {
            (this as LinearLayout.LayoutParams).weight = 0.85f }
        }
```

The app launches OK and when the button is pressed the layout_weight of the linearlayout should update to 0.85f from 0.3 but does not.
There are no error messages generated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `setLayoutParams` to let the change take effect:

```
    predWt.setOnClickListener {
    physWt.layoutParams.apply {
        (this as LinearLayout.LayoutParams).weight = 0.85f }
        physWt.setLayoutParams(this)
    }
```

The reason for this is that the view and its parent view does not know you modified the layout params, by setting it again, `View.requestLayout()` is called for you

Comment: Using the physWt.setLayoutParams(this) as suggested produced an error of wrong inferred type but using physWt.requestLayout() worked. I only mention this for anyone with a similar problem. If I misunderstood your answer, my apologies.

Comment: Any improvements would be gratefully received. I am new to coding and appreciate all help. Thank you for your advice.